# How would I swap 2 values in a function if one value is greater than the other?

Tags: c++, algorithm, function, sorting, c++98

For example I have a function  :`void sort3 (int& a, int& b, int& c)` and I wanted to put the variables in order and only swap if one variable is greater than the other.
for example

```
int v = 3, w = 4, x = 1;`

sort3(v, w, x)
```

I would want v to now equal 1,  w to equal 3, and x to now equal 4. Essentially swapping the value if one variable would be greater than the other. Can someone show me how to do this without using the swap() function as I need this to work with C++ 98.. main function would look something like this:

```
int main()
{
     int u = 2, v = 3, w = 4, x = 1;
    cout << "before: u->" << u << ", v->" << v << endl;
     sort2(u, v);   // u and v are unchanged
     cout << "after: u->" << u << ", v->" << v << endl;
     cout << "\nbefore: w->" << w << ", x->" << x << endl;
     sort2(w, x);   // w now has 1, x has 4
    cout << "after: w->" << w << ", x->" << x << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) routine is the best way to swap two variables.

Comment: I'm quite confident that `std::swap` was already there in C++98, so please elaborate on what your constraints are. Also your question starts talking about a `sort3`, but your snippet shows a couple of `sort2` used on *four* variables. I'm a bit confused on what you are trying to achive.

Answer (score 1):

Only read to add a temp, when you need change value,

```
/*if a > b*/
int temp = a;
a = b;
b = a;
```

Comment: Can be done without using a third variable(`temp` in this case)